# Private IPs accessible on public domain

Tags: docker, networking, dnsmasq

I have 4 docker container running on my docker host and their IPs are 192.168.16.0/24 subnet. Docker host is reachable on my org network and it is in subnet 10.0.0.0/16 subnet but containers are not reachable as they are on private network created using `docker network create` which creates the bridge.

I created the ssh tunnel by mapping the port to docker host and I am able to login to container on a different port using docker host IP.

However, I am looking for a better approach where users can directly access containers from their machine. Can't we make docker host as dnsmasq server and provide the IP of docker host to client ( another machine in the same org on subnet 10.0.0.0/16) to resolve the private subnet? Any idea to handle this situation.

Comment: Use the `docker run -p` option to publish ports out of a container using the host’s IP address.  Never look up or directly the container-private IP addresses; in many common situations like what you’re describing here they just don’t work.

Answer (score 0):

You can create ipvlan/macvlan docker network (https://docs.docker.com/network/macvlan/) with range of addresses from 10.0.0.0 dedicated for these containers, and containers created on this network will be directly exposed to your 10.* network - main limitation of ipvlan/macvlan is inability to communicate with docker host itself, but they could communicate with each other and the rest of network.

Comment: Thanks.  I tested mtacvlan and ipvlan and it works. The problem is that, I cannot lease the IP from my org DNS server. However, I still want to be reach containers from client machine and for that I need a better mechanism. Did anyone tested the same with dnsmasq? is it possible to do with dnsmasq?